# Is it possible to do GPU-accelerated tasks on a raspberry pi?

Tags: gpu, cluster, processor-speed

I have been looking into doing some cluster computing on several raspberry pis. Is it possible to use any kind of GPU acceleration on a pi?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently [Broadcom will never create an openCL implemention](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=3330)  for the GPU, so the short answer is *no*, unless you want to try some tricks with shaders/OGL as suggested in that link.

Looks like someone's [implemented CUDA emulation](http://raspberrypi-hacks.com/23/cuda-on-raspberry-pi-unleash-the-beast/) on the pi, but of course that won't really be using the GPU on RPi. Instead, it is pushing processing to a remote x86 machine with GPU.

Comment: Indeed, that CUDA emulation is pushing the work to a *remote* GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Pete Warden, one of the developers behind TensorFlow, has written a great deal on the Pi’s GPU support. Google is, as they say, your best friend. My earlier answer [Raspberry Pi 4 GPU math](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/116115/raspberry-pi-4-gpu-math) may also be useful.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/130464)