# Can a Pi be used as an OpenCL CPU device?

Tags: networking, gpu, cpu

Can I use a Pi (or, for that matter, Beagle Bone or Arduino) as an OpenCL CPU device?   I understand there isn't much of a GPGPU thing on a Pi, but couldn't I link a bunch together under an OpenCL framework and do something cool and flexible with all that CPU?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to do GPU-accelerated tasks on a raspberry pi?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9391/is-it-possible-to-do-gpu-accelerated-tasks-on-a-raspberry-pi)

Comment: that thread talks specifically of GPUs.  There is no mention of whether or not OpenCL could be used to control the CPUs

Comment: You got me! Did not know CPU manufacturers were doing this too.  So I've retracted my close vote, although I fear the answer is still the same if no one except Intel and AMD have implemented this. +1

Comment: Note that you also need to communicate the input and output to the OpenCL programs.  This might be a bottleneck.

Comment: You'll probably have more succes using the new Parallela board, see [here](http://www.parallella.org/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no OpenCL on the Raspberry Pi [as of 2014](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=3330&sid=e0da4f392412556ecc825d0a1ce50918&start=50).

2018 update; there is now a [work in progress](https://github.com/doe300/VC4CL).

The Arduino is a microcontroller not a SoC (think up to 16000x slower)

The Beagle Bone got [some](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/beagleboard-x15/4j91MoUBKO4/EnXP0zqeCAAJ) in 2015.

[Odroid](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODROID)s have had support since 2013?

Rock64 is missing support [so far](https://forum.pine64.org/showthread.php?tid=5291).

Comment: There is an experimental one since this month, it seems: https://github.com/doe300/VC4CL