# Raspberry Pi 4 GPU math

Tags: pi-4, opengles, computer-vision

So there is support for Open GL ES 3.1, but how can I use it on the Raspberry Pi 4?
Is there any other way to use the GPU for calculations such as fft and logarithm?

Comment: I have the exact same question, except that I'm looking to do image processing in the Videocore. But I can't find anything. Did you end up finding something?

Comment: Sorry, but not really. The only thing I found is related to the MESA graphics library but I haven't researched it any further.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the `boot` partition. There you can find many overlays. Try using them. And install mesa gl driver. Then you can activate them from `raspi-config`

Comment: The RPi4 has an experimental Opengl "fake" kms driver, but I haven't found a good method to use the API to program for it.

Comment: This answer is quite useless I'm afraid to say. You could have posted just a bit more information about what to look for to ease the pain for others.

So, in there ( https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-5.4.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/README ), look for overlays starting with `vc4`. However those seems to be related to display drivers, so they may not do what @Hneggbrand is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to look at Pete Warden's work using Deep Learning for image recognition with the RPi's GPU [here](https://petewarden.com/2014/06/09/deep-learning-on-the-raspberry-pi/). If you want to code using the GPU have a look at [QPILib](https://github.com/mn416/QPULib) which is an astonishing piece of work building a language to code on to the Rpi's GPU using only C++'s macro language.

> QPULib is a programming language and compiler for the Raspberry Pi's
> Quad Processing Units (QPUs). It is implemented as a C++ library that
> runs on the Pi's ARM CPU, generating and offloading programs to the
> QPUs at runtime.

Comment: These work with Videocore IV as do all the others I have seen, while the RPi4 has the newer Videocore VI graphics chip.